# auto-pst-pdf and ucl thesis style

Tags: errors, luatex, auto-pst-pdf

I have a problem with compiling my thesis which uses the ucl latex template style. While I've tried to reduce it to a minimal working example, I'm not sure whether it's still relevant. The error I get when trying to compile my thesis is

```
'PDF inclusion: required page does not exist <1>'.
```

Trying to recreate this I came up with

```
\documentclass[12pt,phd,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemstyle}


\begin{document}
    \begin{scheme}[h!]
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{com:selili}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{RATSMoelcules.eps}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:RATSMols}
\end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

Which works fine with `lualatex --shell-escape --halt-on-error temp.tex` however when I change the document class to `ucl_thesis` the image doesn't appear. Which is a different error to my previous problem, but it may help.

[RATSMoelcules.eps](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpze9wppca7ris9/RATSMoelcules.eps?dl=0)

[ucl_thesis.cls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/va0j1w7qtsqfgaa/ucl_thesis.cls?dl=0)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.